# Getting datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 24, 20, 40, 57) as a value but need to convert to actual date and time

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am querying a database and then passing the results to a function for tuple-to-dictionary conversion by doing the following:

```
 r = {}
 r = [dict((cursor.description[i][0], value)
    for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
 return r
```

This returns a list of dictionaries, but I have two columns that have time created and time updated. I get a dictionary that has key/values like this:

```
 {
 'recCreatedTimeUTC': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 24, 20, 40, 57),
 'recUpdatedTimeUTC': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 24, 20, 40, 57),
 'userID': 92
 }
```

How can i get the datetime.datetime to actually display the date correctly? I can't run it through datetime.datetime with those words there  as part of the value without throwing an error, and I don't know how to extract and convert what I need and put it back. The ultimate goal is to then convert the whole dictionary to a string and return as a body in an API call.

Comment: use `datetime.strftime()`

Answer (score 0):

Taking for example your output:

### MongoDB

If you are using MongoDB you can use `bson` from the pymongo built-in utilities to help with the serialization of json:
http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.10.1/api/bson/json_util.html

Example usage (serialization):

```py
from bson import json_util
import json

r = [{
    'recCreatedTimeUTC': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 24, 20, 40, 57),
    'recUpdatedTimeUTC': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 24, 20, 40, 57),
    'userID': 92
}]

json.dumps(r, default=json_util.default)
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "recCreatedTimeUTC": {
      "$date": 1556138457000
    },
    "recUpdatedTimeUTC": {
      "$date": 1556138457000
    },
    "userID": 92
  }
]
```

### Django

If you are using Django it provides a native DjangoJSONEncoder serializer that deals with date time objects properly.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder

### Custom Default

If you want to use a custom default for the encoder you can do it like this:

```py
import datetime

import json

r = []
r = [{
    'recCreatedTimeUTC': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 24, 20, 40, 57),
    'recUpdatedTimeUTC': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 24, 20, 40, 57),
    'userID': 92
}]


def default(o):
    if isinstance(o, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)):
        return o.isoformat()

print(json.dumps(r, indent=2, default=default))
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "recCreatedTimeUTC": "2019-04-24T20:40:57",
    "recUpdatedTimeUTC": "2019-04-24T20:40:57",
    "userID": 92
  }
]
```